# How to make form top of all other css?

Tags: html, css, forms

I Need to make this simple form style top of all other css.
they are in the same position and they need to be like that.
the .brust in the style is a simple div to create a star
and i tried a few ways but for some reason the form is still under the css 
 div.
how i can do that? thanks.

```css
.burst-6 {
  background: black;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 900px;
  margin-top: -220px;
}

.burst-6:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.burst-6:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class=burst-6>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Em@il" value="">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got to position your 'form' element correctly.

```css
.burst-6 {
  background: black;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -220px;
}

.burst-6:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.burst-6:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.burst-6 form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class=burst-6>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Em@il" value="">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `z-index` of the form so that it sits above the `:after` pseudo element.

```
form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Working example:

```css
.burst-6 {
  background: black;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-left: 900px;
  margin-top: -220px; */ /* removed for demo */
}

.burst-6:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.burst-6:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.burst-6:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.burst-6 form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=burst-6>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Em@il" value="">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set a position and a z-index properties for the form.
 [check this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hdwilber/a2b2fcou/2/)

```
                       *CSS*
                      --------
       *the star style from now to above*
    .burst-6 {
        background: black;
        width: 310px;
        height: 310px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 900px;
        margin-top: -220px;
    }

    .burst-6:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 310px;
        width: 310px;
        background: black;
        background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
    }

    .burst-6:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 310px;
        width: 310px;
        background: black;
        background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
     }

    .burst-6:before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .burst-6:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    }
    .burst-6 > form {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1000;
      }
```